# inputStream = new FileInputStream(path) not working

Tags: java, struts2

1. This is the code in Java Class.
          redflaglight.png image is present in the Images folder
          file not found Null pointer exception is at
          inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
          Struts2.3.5   Java7

   ```
         public String createRootPath() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {  
               String rootPath = "";  
               String path = ExportExcelBusiness.class.getProtectionDomain()  
                       .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();  
               File f = new File(path);  
               String ff = f.getParent();  
               f = new File(ff);  
               ff = f.getParent();  
               f = new File(ff);  
               ff = f.getParent();  
               f = new File(ff);  
               ff = f.getParent();  
               f = new File(ff);  
               ff = f.getParent();    
               f = new File(ff);  
               ff = f.getParent();  
               f = new File(ff);  
               ff = f.getParent();  
               String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(ff, "UTF-8");  
               rootPath = decodedPath.replace('\\', '/');  
               rootPath += "/WebContent/pages/appsresponse/images";  
               return rootPath;  

           }  

           path = createRootPath()+ "/up_arrow_export.png";    
   InputStream inputStream = null;    
                                           int pictureIdx = 0;  
                                           byte[] bytes;  
                                           try {  
                                               inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);  
                                               bytes = IOUtils  
                                                       .toByteArray(inputStream);  
                                               pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes,
                                                       Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);  
                                           } finally {  
                                               if (inputStream != null) {  
                                                   inputStream.close();  
                                               }  
                                           }
   ```

   Though File is present in the path, unable to fetch that file. This started after upgrading from Struts2.2.1 to struts2.3.5

Comment: Do not use absolute pathes in an web application

Comment: I'm using relative path only... To give you clear picture of what the value returns in local i have posted

Comment: *D:/480499_Workspace* is an absolute path!

Comment: Also post an [MCVE]. an describe what you want to do

Comment: Please put in a bit of effort and put all of that code in your question itself.

Comment: Do not put code as comment. Add the code to your question using the edit function

Comment: Your code mixes `URL` paths (`ExportExcelBusiness.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()`) with file system paths (`File.getParent()`) which is in itself a recipe for disaster. And then: why do you traverse seven levels up in the file system hierarchy?

Comment: Oh dear. It's not clear what you're trying to do--I'm pretty sure this isn't a good approach. You should not be referring to `WebContent` since that is an IDE artifact. If you want to access images from *within the web app* they should either be classpath resources, or stored externally to the web content, the name of that directory configured in any number of ways, and referenced directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this code on server and using relative path then, your file should be inside server directory. like:-

```
your_server_path/pages/appsresponse/images
```

Problem is you are keeping your images in workspace, you need to keep that in server directory.

**EDIT**
Verify your path

```
File file=new File(path);
System.out.print(file.getAbsolutePath()); //check whether file is present at this path or not
```

Comment: let me know how to get it work in local. Because in server directory files are placed already.

Comment: What exactly you are asking, i dont get it

Comment: Though up_arrow_export.png is available, it is unable to find that. This started after upgradation from struts2.2.1 to Struts2.3.5

Comment: @InduKumar check EDITs in post